# pinglish gem - how to log result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware

I'm using pinglish to expose _ping endpoint and making few checks like db and cache.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.middleware.use Pinglish do |ping|
    ping.check :redis do
      //check redis status
      'ok'
    end

    ping.check :db do
      //some active record statement 
      'ok'
    end
  end
end
```

Above is my configuration. Now when _ping fails I'm getting monitor alert but I do not know what exactly is down(db or reddis) so is there anyway to log the output when it fails like a hook?

Answer (score 0):

Any failed checks will be listed in the "failures" key of the ping response (documented [here](https://github.com/jbarnette/pinglish#an-example-response)). For example, if your "redis" check failed, you would get a response like this

```
{
   ....
   "failures": ["redis"],
   .....
}
```